How does the law interpret the Ship of Theseus Paradox?
Suppose, for instance, you have a car. If you Ship of Theseus it (or Car of Theseus it, I guess), and replace all of its parts with new parts over time, and then construct a new car out of the replaced parts, in the eyes of the law, which car would be the original? If you, say, had gotten the original car insured, would the car made of new parts or the car made of the original parts be insured?
Please note, I chose a car just as an example, if cars are given special treatment in this case, and it would be better to use some other object, feel free to do so.

What if you sold the old parts to a used parts store, someone else buys them, and uses them to construct a new car? This reminds me of the teleportation paradox

@Barmar, did you read my answer?  Is anything lacking?

@MichaelHall I'm not refuting your answer, my comment was an attempt to reframe the question.

@Barmar, but you didn't reframe it, you simply paraphrased the same hypothetical situation with a subtle twist.


How does the law interpret the Ship of Theseus Paradox?

It doesn't.
The law is more pragmatic and less abstract in these sort of specific situations.  Your car has a Vehicle Identification Number, (VIN) in a location that is difficult to modify.  It may be stamped into the frame itself, or on a plaque between the frame and windshield.  The VIN identifies that car for legal purposes.  (licensing, registration, etc.)
If in the process of repair, (or restoration of an antique car) the VIN becomes obliterated or exists in an uncoded format not compatible with modern standards, the law will generally provide a means to clarify or re-identify the vehicle.  (for example, in Washington State you must schedule a vehicle inspection by the State Patrol to establish the VIN for titling purposes)
Basically any object the state may take an interest in controlling in some manner will have a means of identifying it by some sort of serial number.  (Cars, boats, trailers, firearms, etc.)  The part that is serialized is the "thing", all other parts may be swapped without regard and the legal identity of the thing will remain intact.
For an object in your possession that doesn't require a title or registration the law generally doesn't care if you fully rebuild it, so there is no paradox from a legal standpoint.

This is a solid answer, but let's imagine that there's an accident where the part containing the VIN got knocked off the car and couldn't (initially) be found. The owner rebuilds the car and has the car re-identified. Later, they find the part that was lost (and contained the original VIN), as well as other parts of the car and created a "clone". I suspect the law just wouldn't have anything explicit to say about this far-fetched example, but let me know if I'm wrong.

@BenHocking, good question.  First, if the part containing the VIN "got knocked off" there's probably a 99% chance the car would be unrepairable scrap.  Second, if it was rebuilt it would be issued a salvage title with the same VIN so no history would be lost.  Because even minus a plaque the VIN is known.  Any "clone" seeking a title under that same VIN would reasonably be refused, and the owner would have to have it inspected and re-identified under the VIN of the frame it was built on, or a whole new number created.

"I suspect the law just wouldn't have anything explicit to say..."  But it would, maybe not in so many words, but it would certainly prevent two cars with the same VIN from being titled and registered in the same state even if the means of prevention were more procedural than regulatory.  (i.e. Computer system programmed to not issue a second title...)

Law does not "interpret" philosophical allegories.
Whether a reconstituted object is considered original or not will depend on the how the issue arises. In many cases, the fact that an object was reconstituted with new material will be irrelevant to the legal issue.
For example, objects in your house considered "effects" insured under home insurance are generally insured no matter whether they are original or not. My computer is insured because it's my computer in my house, not because it is an "original" computer.
In most or all North American jurisdictions, an automobile is insured based on its vehicle identification number. Whether it is has been substantially remade may play a role in determining the value to be reimbursed upon loss, but that is simply a question of appraisal, not one of "originality."
When you sell a product on the basis of a representation that it is in its "original" condition, that may indeed convey the meaning that it is unaltered. If so, then it does matter whether aspects of the "original" have been replaced.
Some jurisdictions "grandfather" prior legal non-conforming use. A structure that was formerly allowed, but now would be disallowed because of a zoning change, is permitted to continue to exist, unless some high proportion of the structure is damaged or destroyed at any one time.

It depends, there will in some specific cases be a minimum amount of the original item that needs to remain to still be considered the original. In the specific domain of construction, for example, it's common in some jurisdictions to build a "new " house by tearing down an old one, but leaving one wall standing, allowing the construction project to be considered a renovation of an existing house rather than a new construction project, which might have more stringent permit or code requirements. By leaving at least one exterior wall, the building may be considered the same house, not a new one.
